# How can i get the proper format for series using label?

Tags: vb.net

just wondering about my problem in making series numbers . Does someone knows about this?

```
Dim series As String = "0000"
Dim adds As New SqlCommand("Select MAX (IR_No) from IR_ActionTaken",conn)

conn.Open()
Form43.label_irno.Text = Format("00000", adds.ExecuteScalar() + 1)
conn.Close()
```

Comment: Did you try string.padLeft() ? What output you are expecting ? Can you give an example or two ?

Comment: for example : " IR No. 00001"  
i was thinking if it reached series 10 it will become "000010" not "00010"

Comment: I have to ask, why bother? Why not just keep the series number an actual number (1, 2, 3 ...100, 101).

Comment: because it's an actual format of a series number in a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use String.padLeft specifying total length you would like. For example, following c# code snippet keeps total string length 20 and adjust the padding according to the actual string length.

```
Dim myString as String 
myString = "Hello World!"
debug.print(myString.PadLeft(20,"-")
```

Comment: I am using vb .

Comment: Dim myString as String
debug.print(myString.PadLeft(5,"0")

Comment: your codes like from cs because of " ; " which is vb doesn't had. i'll try your code and update you in a minute.

Comment: Dim series String = "0000"
i need to get 
Label1.text = Format.String(series, cmd.executescalar +1) something like that.

Comment: Kimosave, you'll have to try yourself. There won't be a spoon-feeding. The code I gave works and I just tested it. All you have to do is to use output of SQL, add 1, as per your need and use .PadLeft(). The PadLeft in conjunction with total length does precisely what you need.

Comment: i tried it already and it just adding like what i code lately.
Expectation: 00010 (supposed to be 5 digits only from default value of 00000)
Reality: 0000010

Comment: You must have made a mistake somewhere. Give your code with .PadLeft() increasing the length or look here - https://pastebin.com/ejZs3FFJ. The length of output text remains constant and is equal to the specified length.